# Data from parse.com is not displayed when internet is unavailable (cache available)

Tags: android, caching, nullpointerexception, parse-platform

I've been struggling with this for the past few days. I'm fetching data from a class at parse.com. The data is fetched and is displayed correctly when an internet connection is available BUT when it's not, it doesn't display the cached data and the app crashes. Yes, I ran the app with an internet connection first so result would be cached. This is how I get the data:

```
    worldpopulationlist = new ArrayList<BulletinItem>();
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
    query.setCachePolicy(ParseQuery.CachePolicy.NETWORK_ELSE_CACHE);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> postList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
             worldpopulationlist.clear();
            for (ParseObject news : postList) {
                 ParseFile image = (ParseFile) news.get("thumbnail");
                    BulletinItem map = new BulletinItem();
                    map.setthumbnail(image.getUrl());
                    map.setpostedBy((String) news.get("postedBy"));
                    // other stuff
                    worldpopulationlist.add(map);
              }
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });
```

And here I check if a cached result is available while the app is still connected to the internet, this always returns true.

```
boolean isCached = query.hasCachedResult();
if (isCached == true) Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "cache is available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

And this is the NPE trace coming from the parse sdk when there is no internet available:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(21769): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(21769):    at com.parse.ParseQuery$15.then(ParseQuery.java:763)
E/AndroidRuntime(21769):    at com.parse.ParseQuery$15.then(ParseQuery.java:1)
E/AndroidRuntime(21769):    at com.parse.Task$10.run(Task.java:442)
E/AndroidRuntime(21769):    at com.parse.Task$1.execute(Task.java:67)
E/AndroidRuntime(21769):    at com.parse.Task$6.then(Task.java:309)
```

Comment: The error occurred because of the way the code was written, I fixed mine. Please post yours somewhere so I can take a look.